# WCF and Castle library (Glass Mapper)

Tags: wcf, sitecore, sitecore6, glass-mapper

hello I have WCF service with `webHttpEndpointBehavior` under Sitecore 6 and I use Glass Mapper to read items, Glass mapper has depends on Castle library.

It is working well, but i have some methods with Contract like:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<Shade> GetAllShades(int columns, int rows);
```

where I try return list of my class in JSON format,
during debug my service with SvcTraceViewer.exe I find out next error:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   :GetFamilyShadesResult. The InnerException message was 'Type
>   'Castle.Proxies.ShadeProxy' with data contract name
>   'ShadeProxy:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Castle.Proxies' is
>   not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types
>   not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by
>   using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list
>   of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

How to resole this issue? `Castle.Proxies.ShadeProxy` is a dynamic class under Castle and I can't use  `KnownTypeAttribute`.

Actually if I JSON.net library and return results as string everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you have a class that links to other classes loaded via Glass, e.g.

```
[SitecoreClass]
public class Shade{

    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual IEnumerable<AnotherClass> SomeField{get;set;}

    [SitecoreChildren]
    public virtual IEnumerable<AnotherClass> Children{get;set;}      
}
[SitecoreClass]
public class AnotherClass{}
```

To allow lazy loading of classes Glass uses proxies generated by Castle, so at runtime when the classes are loaded into the SomeField property you actually get a sub-class of the AnotherClass class.

To resolve this you have to explicitly tell class to load the other classes as concrete types, updating the SitecoreField attribute should fix this problem:

```
[SitecoreClass]
public class Shade{

    [SitecoreField(Setting=SitecoreFieldSettings.DontLazyLoad)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<AnotherClass> SomeField{get;set;}

    [SitecoreChildren(IsLazy=false)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<AnotherClass> Children{get;set;}
}
[SitecoreClass]
public class AnotherClass{}
```

Comment: @Michael: How do I combine settings? I.e. for `public virtual IEnumerable<AnotherClass> SomeField{get;set;}` I want to disable lazy load and also enable `InferType`. Is this possible?